# I want to create a method that uses dot(.) operator while calling in JAVA

Tags: java

I wanted to create a method that uses `.` while calling.

```
String A="Alpha",B="Beta";
A.compareTo(B);
```

So how to access `A` to define the method `compareTo()`. I can access the `String B` in definition of `compareTo()`, but to compare `B` with I need `A` as well. How can I access `A`. In the definition of the method.

Answer (score 2):

`String` *already* has a [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-).

If you're talking about adding new methods to existing classes without access to the class's source, like C#'s extension methods, that doesn't exist in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, Do you want to use `'this'` keyword.

`'this'` gives you access to the current object on which the method is invoked.